# robot-framework: embedded screenshot with preview thumbnail

Tags: python, html, base64, robotframework

So in case of failure in my test I want to embedded `screenshot`:

```
b_64 = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
logger.info(f'<img width="500" src="data:image/png;base64, {b_64}" alt="Red dot"/>', html=True)
```

I don't want to put the `screenshot` in full size so in my example here i am using custom `size` (500)
So my question is if is it possible to add small preview `screenshot` and once the user click it it become in full size ?

Comment: most likely possible with either onclick event in the img tag to show full size image or with just pure css on hover - you probably can get better answers if y

Comment: Any change for code example ?